# ListView ContextMenu in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment, contextmenu

In Fragment onCreateView i have the following code

```
consumerlist=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.consumerlist);
    consumerlist.setAdapter(new consumerListAdapter(getActivity(), dataList));
    consumerlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ID"+id, 1);

        }
    });
    Button btn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    registerForContextMenu(consumerlist);
    return view;
```

if i write      registerForContextMenu(btn) then it works.but list view row long click does nothing.Even my listView onItemClick listener does not work.how to fix it?Anybody helps me greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
consumerlist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          registerForContextMenu( view );
          openContextMenu( view );        

        return false;
    }
});
```

also [this](http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/) tutorial should help you a lot ...

**//EDIT**

Move

```
registerForContextMenu(consumerlist);
```

to

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove scollview in layout or define it as not focusable make the code working.